# Passing php generated result back to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to pass the result that is generated by PHP back to javascript. As the php_script_response gave me the result of success[{"result":"2gGtqA"}] after I have successfully uploaded my image. I would want to just retrieve back the "2gGtqA" and store the name into my database instead of the whole "{"result":"2gGtqA"}".

when call upload.php it will generate a sample " [{"result":"78GAVe"}]"

**addfacilities.php**

```html
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

error_reporting(E_ERROR);

include("global.php");

try{
 $conn = new mysqli(server, dbuser, dbpw, db);
 $facilities_ID = $_GET["facilities_ID"];
 $facilities_Img = $_GET["facilities_Img"];

 
 $query = "INSERT Facilities set facilities_ID = '" . $facilities_ID . "'
 , facilities_Img = '" . $facilities_Img . "'";



 $result = $conn->query($query);

 if (!$result){
  $json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>0)) . "]";  
 }
 else {
  $json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>1)) . "]";  
 }

 echo $json_out;

 $conn->close();
}
catch(Exception $e) {
 $json_out =  "[".json_encode(array("result"=>0))."]";
 echo $json_out;
}
?>
```

**upload.php**

```html
<?php
try{
    if (0 < $_FILES['file']['error']) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    } else {

        $filename = tempnam('images', '');
        $new_image_name = basename(preg_replace('"\.tmp$"', '.jpg', $filename));
        unlink($filename);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $new_image_name);

        echo "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>$new_image_name)) . "]";
    }
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    $json_out =  "[".json_encode(array("result"=>0))."]";
    echo $json_out;
}
?>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="span10 offset1">
      <form action="#" method="post" name="form_name" id="createform" class="form_class" >

        <div class="control-group ">
           <label class="control-label">Facilities ID</label>
               <div class="controls">
               <input type="text" name="facilities_ID" id="facilities_ID" placeholder="Facilities name">
               </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Facilities Image</label>
          <div class="controls">
             <img id="imgNewUser" height="100">
             <input type="file" name="SelectImg" id="SelectImg" value="My Picture" accept="image/*" onchange="onpreviewFile()">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="upload-button" onclick="createfacilities()">Update</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
      <script>
        function onpreviewFile() {
            var preview = document.querySelector('img'); //selects the query named img
            var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; //sames as here
            var reader  = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = function () {
                preview.src = reader.result;
            }

            if (file) {
                reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
                //uploadFile(); // testing
            } else {
                preview.src = "";
            }
        }

        onpreviewFile();

       function uploadFile() {
            var file_data = $('#SelectImg').prop('files')[0];   
            var form_data = new FormData();                  
            form_data.append('file', file_data); // The name here ('file') needs to match what PHP is expecting


            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
                dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                type: 'post',
                success: function(php_script_response){
                    alert("success" + php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
                    _imageresult(php_script_response);
                }
             });
            }

            function _imageresult(php_script_response){
            if (php_script_response !== ""){
               alert("yes image1" + php_script_response.new_image_name);
             } else {
                 alert("no upload");
             }
        }

        function createfacilities() {
            var image = document.getElementById("SelectImg").files[0].name;
            document.getElementById("createform").submit(); //form submission
           document.getElementById("createform").submit(); //form submission
            alert("facilities_ID : " + facilities_ID 
             + "\n\n Form Submitted Successfully.");


            var facilities_ID  = $("#facilities_ID").val();
            //var image1= response; // i would want to get the php_script_response                //alert ("image1 >>>" + image1);

            var url = "http://mp08.mybitmp.org/adelinetest/addfacilities.php";


            var JSONObject = {
                "facilities_ID": facilities_ID,
               //"facilities_Img" : image,
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                data: JSONObject,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (arr) {
                   uploadFile();
                   _addDescriptionResult(arr);

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("not okay");
                }
            });
        }

        function _addDescriptionResult(arr) {
            document.getElementById("facilities_ID").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("facilities_ID");
            if (arr[0].result === 1) {
                alert("okay");
            } else {
                alert("not okay 1");
            }
        }
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are you getting so far? what this variable $new_image_name returns? an array or an object? if an object you can pull it like object->value. Seeing your code, you're passing it into an array. please be clear

Comment: You don't need to do `echo "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>$new_image_name)) . "]";` ~ simply `echo json_encode(array("result"=>$new_image_name));` should suffice

Comment: If you want to save this value into your database, why not do it from your upload.php file. There is no need to return it as an AJAX response to process later on. Or have you got other "things" going on...

Comment: @Adeline So have you designated somewhere on your page where you are going to save this to? Will it be in a hidden form text input so you can submit it later with your other values?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw hi, I have just edited my code. Could you help me take a look? I hope to get the image name that the uploaded.php have generated and createfacilities() will save both the facilites_ID and the image together.